# How to add v-click-outside in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<ul class="list-inline" v-if="showSearchHistory">

          <li
            class="list-inline-item list-group-item-primary"
            v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory
              .slice(-5)
              .reverse()
              .map((s) => s.trim())"
            :key="index"
            @click="selectPreviousSearch(index)"
          >
            {{ item }}
          </li>
<div class="line-separator">
 
</div>

</ul>
```

```js
methods: {
  enter() {
    this.selection = this.matches[this.current];
    this.open = false;

  },

  onClick() {
    this.showSearchHistory = true;
  },
  change() {
    this.showSearchHistory = false;
  },
  inputChanged(event) {
    if (event.code == "ArrowUp" || event.code == "ArrowDown")
      return;

    this.filteredUsers = [];

    if (event.code == "Enter")
      return;

    var filtered = this.users.filter((user) => {
      return user.text.match(this.search)
    });

    this.isOpen = true
    this.filteredUsers.push(...filtered)


    // console.log(this.filteredUsers)
  },
  closeSearch() {
    this.showSearchHistory = true;
  },
}
```

```html
<input
  class="form-control bg-light-blue"
  id="SearchText"
  type="text"
  v-model="search"
  @keydown.enter="enter"
  @click="onClick"
  @keyup.enter="processSearch"
  @input="change"
  @keyup="inputChanged"
  @keydown.down="onArrow"
  @keydown.up="onArrow"
  @keydown.space="preventLeadingSpace"
  @focusout="closeSearch"
/>
```

I have an search field, When i clicked on Search, Li tag will display,

And now i need to close the Li tag, when i clicked outside of search

So in order to close li tag, Taken @focusout="closeSearch" and writeen one method for that, But now the problem is, even if i click on li tag also it's closing.

Comment: Maybe start by adding an `@focusout="closeSearch"` event on your input? Then close the search :)

Comment: Written method for @focusout="closeSearch", 
closeSearch(){
        this.showSearchHistory = true;
      },

But now the problem is even if i click on li tag also, li tag is closing

Comment: If i click outside li tag, then li tag should close.. I have updated my code, can u please check that.

Comment: Two aspect here, focus out is working well, anywhere out of the input, it trigger the event and close the li tag. Now the problem with even clicking on li tag, it close the tag, if I understood correctly. For usability I would suggest to keep this behavior all global search of any app or even google search, you get the list, you click outside the search box or on list item (search result) it fill the input and list disappear. And that's how users adapted to use ? May I know it  why you want to do otherwise ?

Comment: Yes u r right. But in this  scenario, on list item (search result) it fill the input and list disappear. Problem is, It is not filling the input and simply it is closing the li tag. after adding the code closeSearch() {
    this.showSearchHistory = true;
  },

Comment: And it's even closing li tag, if i click any where in li tag (on data and in empty area also)

Comment: Maybe try to play with the [vue-click-outside](https://github.com/vue-bulma/click-outside#readme) directive. But you'll have to the directive on a common parent for both input and the list. Or you can check the $event trigger from this directive and not close if the `$event.target` is a children of your list.

Comment: Ok. Going through that. If possible can you please give me some example for the above code. like where do i need to place the functionality in mine.

Comment: you can use this directive from vueUse : https://vueuse.org/core/onclickoutside/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the directive that I use in my projects:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

const HAS_WINDOWS = typeof window !== 'undefined';
const HAS_NAVIGATOR = typeof navigator !== 'undefined';
const IS_TOUCH = HAS_WINDOWS && ('ontouchstart' in window || (HAS_NAVIGATOR && navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
const EVENTS = IS_TOUCH ? ['touchstart'] : ['click'];
const IDENTITY = (item) => item;

const directive = {
  instances: [],
};

function processDirectiveArguments (bindingValue)
{
  const isFunction = typeof bindingValue === 'function';
  if (!isFunction && typeof bindingValue !== 'object')
  {
    throw new Error('v-click-outside: Binding value must be a function or an object');
  }

  return {
    handler: isFunction ? bindingValue : bindingValue.handler,
    middleware: bindingValue.middleware || IDENTITY,
    events: bindingValue.events || EVENTS,
    isActive: !(bindingValue.isActive === false),
  };
}

function onEvent ({ el, event, handler, middleware })
{
  const isClickOutside = event.target !== el && !el.contains(event.target);

  if (!isClickOutside)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (middleware(event, el))
  {
    handler(event, el);
  }
}

function createInstance ({ el, events, handler, middleware })
{
  return {
    el,
    eventHandlers: events.map((eventName) => ({
      event: eventName,
      handler: (event) => onEvent({
        event,
        el,
        handler,
        middleware
      }),
    })),
  };
}

function removeInstance (el)
{
  const instanceIndex = directive.instances.findIndex((instance) => instance.el === el);
  if (instanceIndex === -1)
  {
    // Note: This can happen when active status changes from false to false
    return;
  }

  const instance = directive.instances[instanceIndex];

  instance.eventHandlers.forEach(({ event, handler }) =>
    document.removeEventListener(event, handler)
  );

  directive.instances.splice(instanceIndex, 1);
}

function bind (el, binding)
{
  const { events, handler, middleware, isActive } = processDirectiveArguments(binding.value);

  if (!isActive)
  {
    return;
  }

  const instance = createInstance({
    el,
    events,
    handler,
    middleware
  });

  instance.eventHandlers.forEach(({ event, handler }) =>
    setTimeout(() => document.addEventListener(event, handler), 0)
  );
  directive.instances.push(instance);
}

function update (el, { value, oldValue })
{
  if (JSON.stringify(value) === JSON.stringify(oldValue))
  {
    return;
  }

  const { events, handler, middleware, isActive } = processDirectiveArguments(value);

  if (!isActive)
  {
    removeInstance(el);
    return;
  }

  let instance = directive.instances.find((instance) => instance.el === el);

  if (instance)
  {
    instance.eventHandlers.forEach(({ event, handler }) =>
      document.removeEventListener(event, handler)
    );
    instance.eventHandlers = events.map((eventName) => ({
      event: eventName,
      handler: (event) => onEvent({
        event,
        el,
        handler,
        middleware
      }),
    }));
  }
  else
  {
    instance = createInstance({
      el,
      events,
      handler,
      middleware
    });
    directive.instances.push(instance);
  }

  instance.eventHandlers.forEach(({ event, handler }) =>
    setTimeout(() => document.addEventListener(event, handler), 0)
  );
}

directive.bind = bind;
directive.update = update;
directive.unbind = removeInstance;

Vue.directive('click-outside', directive);
```

Comment: Thanks with the above code of my fine, i tried to do that... But struck at beginning with related to my code.

Comment: You will have a variable `showLI` which is initially FALSE. When you focus inside the search field - you will set this variable to TRUE so that `<li v-show="showLI">` can react. And you will add `v-click-outside="closeLI"` to the search field. The `closeLI` function will set the variable `showLI` to FALSE.